# Unexpected behavior of grep command in C program

Tags: c, grep

Consider the following two text files:

`def.txt`

```
simple =
"sik", /* fill */
"trauma", /* type */
"hui", /* col */
```

`def.dat`

```
simple =
"sik", /* fill */
"trauma", /* type */
"hui", /* col */
```

The above 2 files are stored in `examples` directory.

The following `grep` command works fine as expected:

```
$ grep --include=*.{txt,dat} -rnw example/ -F -e 'simple'
example/def.dat:1:simple =
example/def.txt:1:simple =
$ echo $? => 0
```

But when I execute the above `grep` command in C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char cmd[1024];

  strcpy (cmd, "grep --include=*.{txt,dat} -rnw example/ -F -e 'simple'");
  printf ("%d\n", system (cmd));
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is `256`.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not bash. `/bin/sh` does not support brace expansions. Try running that command through `/bin/sh` manually and it won't work either.

Comment: @EtanReisner Does this mean there is no other solution to run this grep command in C?

Comment: It means you can't use bash-specific features in a `system` call like that. So either write out the full command (avoid the brace expansion) or manually run `bash` in the command passed to `system` (which means careful extra quoting).

Comment: @EtanReisner Could you please tell me how can I run `bash` in the command passed to `system`?

Comment: That's the worse option (the quoting is non-trivial) but it would be something like `/bin/bash -c 'your command'` only with sufficient quote mangling to make it work correctly (of which there is a lot for any complex command).

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks a lot. Is it possible for you to make this as an answer. This helped me a lot.

Comment: @Shahzad: Note that running a shell from your program code without precautions is a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is not bash. `/bin/sh` does not support brace expansions. Try running that command through `/bin/sh` manually and it won't work either.

Your choices are to write out the command manually (do the brace expansion yourself) or wrap your command in `/bin/bash -c '......'` and ensure you've provided enough quote escaping to keep your desired command intact that way (which is complicated and ugly).

The other option is to not do this at all. Either by using a script that you execute (with an appropriate shebang line) or (better) by finding native solutions to the task you need to solve.